# Finite generation of certain graded sequences of ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be an open set containing the origin $o$ and $Y\subset U$ a complex ***analytic*** subvariety of pure codimension $c$ with ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Y$. Let $\frak{a}_{\bullet}=\{{\frak{a}}_\it{m}\}$ be a graded sequence of ideal sheaves on $U$ given by $\frak{a}_\it{m}\rm:=\mathcal{I}_\it Y^{<cm>}$, where $\mathcal{I}_Y^{<p>}$ is the $p$-th symbolic power of $\mathcal{I}_Y$.

If the log canonical threshold $\text{LCT}_o(\frak{a}_{\bullet})=\rm 1$ at $o$, how can we establish that there exists an open neighborhood $V\subset\subset U$ of $o$ such that the Rees algebra of $\frak{a}_{\bullet}$ is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_U$-algebra on $V$?

Answer (score 0):

The best (algebraic) advice I can give is to look at section 2.2.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.03538.pdf
( Uniqueness of K-polystable degenerations of Fano varieties by Blum and Xu)
(eventually, this follows from BCHM)

When the sequence $\mathfrak{a}_m$ is the induce by an exceptional divisor which is an extraction, finite generation follows from ampleness.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the algebraic case, the work of Blum and Xu is enough. However, i don't know whether the work of BCHM is available in the analytic setting for the local case. Thank you very much.